# My SplashScreen doesn't change to my image

Tags: flutter, image, splash-screen, android-launcher, android-splashscreen

[image: Problem]

I am not sure what is wrong because I directly get an error even if I don't change anything (`android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />`).

Comment: have you replaced the launch_image on every single "drawable" folder? If you don't then the correct folder will be assigned to your device and that may not be the one with your image.

Comment: I've done it but it still shows the error